# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object? PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /.../public_html/deals/includes/deal.php on line 7

I already created a database for deal and inserted all the tables with sample data.

index.php (isnt finished yet)

```
include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/deal.php');

$deal = new Deal;
$deals = $deal->fetch_all();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GameDeals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/deals.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<!-- START GAMEDEALS -->

<?php foreach ($deals as $deal) { ?>

<div>dsdsd<?php echo $deal['deal_title']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- END GAMEDEALS -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php 

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', $**username**, $**pwd**);
    } 

catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        return "Database connection error.";
    }

?>
```

deal.php

```
<?php

class Deal {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM deals");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}

?>
```

Any ideas?

```
    <?php

class Deal {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;

        var_dump($pdo);
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM deals");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}

?>
```

Result:

> NULL 
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /.../public_html/deals/includes/deal.php on line 8

Comment: Add `var_dump($pdo)` inside your fetch_all function and see what $pdo is.

Comment: I have no idea... :/ In which file and where?

Comment: Add `var_dump($pdo)` just before the prepare call, and see what that outputs.

Comment: I'm guessing it's like this? `<?php

class Deal {
 public function fetch_all() {
  global $pdo;
  
  var_dump($pdo);
  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM deals");
  $query->execute();
  
  return $query->fetchAll();
 }
}

?>` Results: NULL 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /.../public_html/deals/includes/deal.php on line 8

Comment: Yep. That will print out some information about what the `$pdo` variable is - run the code and edit the result into your question, please.

Comment: Your database connection isn't being made - I've just noticed that your connection code is using a `return` statement in the `catch` line, which will have no effect. Try swapping that over to `die` - and also take note of @saturnix's answer - are you declaring the username and password anywhere before including them in the connection?

Comment: ^ I think not, since he's posting the whole code. Might be wrong, btw! We'll never know until he posts the var_dump.

Comment: I dont believe this is too localized at all. The password wasn't working and the answers leading up to this provide troubleshooting steps for beginners to ensure you have a proper PDO connection to MySQL.  as well as!  Don't use $ as the first character in your passwords as the password may be seen as variables!  (or make sure it has double quotes) w/e there is a lot to learn from this question and I believe it does affect the broad portion of internet users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', $**username**, $**pwd**);
```

where are you declaring `$**username**` and `$**pwd**` ? Nowhere it seems. Declare the 2 values correctly before using the pdo object.

---

Also, replace `return "Database connection error.";` with `printf($e);` and post back with what you see.

Comment: both `$**username**` and `$password` is already entered.

Comment: I can't see them in your code - did you have another portion of the code you didn't posted?

Comment: sorry but i just changed it to `$username` for personal purpose. it's always there.

Comment: Results: `exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'peerawat'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/peerawat/public_html/deals/includes/connection.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/peerawat/public_html/deals/includes/connection.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', NULL, NULL) #1 /home/peerawat/public_html/deals/index.php(3): include_once('/home/peerawat/...') #2 {main}NULL 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/peerawat/public_html/deals/includes/deal.php on line 8`

Comment: this is my new connection.php `<?php 

try {
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=peerawat_gamedeals', $peerawat_gduser, $sewfefsad3134);
 } 

catch (PDOException $e)
    {
     printf($e);
    }

?>

Comment: is $sewfefsad3134 declared or is that your password? If it is your password, you should change "$sewfefsad3134" to "sewfefsad3134".

Comment: i changed it and i think it worked? result: `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
dsdsdtest`

Comment: yay it worked! Thank you both so much saturnix and andrewsi. :)